# Add logic to Jboss startup/shutdown

Tags: jboss, ejb, startup

How is it possible to run some EJB logic during the server start/stop ?
I am using JBoss 5 and EJB 3.0.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Server start is relatively easy: Add a servlet that is called with load-on-startup 1 so that it gets started early and can then initialize stuff on the system in it's `init()` method. As the deployers first deploy ejbs and then servlets, you should be good here to use the ejbs from within the servlet.

When the app shuts down, the servlet's `destroy()` method is (supposed to be) called, so you could shutdown stuff from there.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitShutdownServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Init Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.acme.InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. I just wanted to add that the same thing can be done with Annotations now: 

`@WebServlet(loadOnStartup = 1)
public class InitShutdownServlet extends HttpServlet { ...
`

Answer (score 0):

MBeans can be used as JBoss provides ServiceMBean interface & ServiceMBeanSupport abstract class to execute custom code during startup/shutdown.

Override life-cycle callback methods to add custom logic.

For further reference, see [JBoss Service](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExampleHelloWorldService)